# How to convert a string or character to its unicode representation and back?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe

I'm in the process of learning more about Unicode. Could someone please demonstrate how to translate a code point value to a character string and vice-versa.

For example: How do you convert `U+0037` to its character or string representation which is `7`.

Please also show how to do this for ascii. For example: convert `&nbsp;` to its character or string representation which is a space.

Comment: It's easy enough to parse the string and then use `chr()` to get a character. That will be fine for code points in the BMP. HTML entities are something else altogether.

Comment: David is it as simple as s:=chr('&nbsp;') or maybe s:=chr('U+0037');?

Comment: First of all you have to read the docs of `chr()`. Then parse the code point ordianl out of `'U+0037'`. And html entities are completely different. Get a database of those.

Comment: Yeah had feeling I was gonna need some database but I thought delphi would come with one. Well I guess I will have to search for a Unicode Table online and parse it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi strings already use Unicode (UTF16) encoding, so there is no need to "convert" delphi strings to Unicode. Here is an example how to insert a Unicode representation of nbsp (U+00A0) and '7' (U+0037') into a delphi string directly:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  U_nbsp = $00A0;
  U_7 = $0037;

var
  S: string;

begin
  S:= 'abcd' + Char(U_nbsp) + Char(U_7);
  ShowMessage(S);
end;
```

Comment: Sir, I see the use of const, but what if you don't know the item you are going to decode?

Comment: @megatr0n replace `const` by `var`?

Comment: @megatr0n If you have the Unicode jump code in **U+0000** format, you can parse it for the hex digits then use the `StrToInt()` function to convert it to an integer.

Comment: @megatron However it does not solve the **&nbsp;** related problem, because it is not a Unicode jumpcode representation.

Comment: I think `chr()` is better than the cast

Comment: HTML codes like `&nsbp;` can only be decoded or coded using a database that knows these names and knows the numerical representations of those. If such a function does not exist somewhere, someone will have to write it. Can't be too hard. I would use a TDictionary<string, UInt32> for that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Chr *is*, in effect, a cast. It does not produce any code (except the usual Byte to Word expansion, which the cast would produce too), AFAICT.

Comment: @rudy the end result is the same but it is semantically more accurate I believe

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ok, the end result is the same. I am not sure which is semantically more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TFrm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  TabEmoj.Text:=#$1F604;
  KeyEmojisActivator.Text:=#$1F604;
  Attachbutton.Text:=#$1F4CE;
   VideoAudiobutton.Text:=#$1F3A5;  /// MIC = #$1F3A4;
   EnterButton.Text:=#$21A9;
end;  
// use this. Download example on u9.by
```